# Why my emails go to junk folder?

Tags: email, spam-prevention, dkim, spf, rdns

I registered a new .xyz domain name a few days ago. The domain name was never registered by others before. I set up a postfix server on a clean ip(checked its reputation). I set up SPF, DKIM, and reverse DNS. I composed a simple email(subject: hello world, content: this is a test email) destined to outlook.com. But the email from this domain goes to outlook's junk email folder. How should I do to avoid this? And how to decode the outlook email headers related to spam such as: SpamDiagnosticOutput: 1:99 SpamDiagnosticMetadata: NSPM X-Microsoft-Antispam-Message-Info: X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:

Comment: Doublecheck your SPF records. They need to be the IP address of where you are sending the mail from.

Comment: The SPF is:v=spf1 a mx  ~all, Do you mean it should be like :v=spf1 a mx  ipv4:xx.xx.xx.xx ~all? But the email header show spf:pass

Comment: Even if you do everything within your control, messages can still go to a recipient's Junk Mail folder for reasons beyond your control. This makes your question unanswerable unfortunately.

Comment: I doubt the brand-new domain causes the problem. So I want to know if anybody else has the same experience.

Comment: There are websites to check your spf record. I'm pretty sure they'll help you identify your problem.

Comment: I send a test email to check-auth@verifier.port25.com, the response shows all pass. The email headers in the email to outlook also show spf:pass.

Comment: It doesn’t appear to be an SPF record problem. But we don’t have enough details to determine why your mail is going to junk. It might be possible to learn more if we had the entire set of email headers on the Outlook side. But even then, Microsoft is secretive about their rules, as they don’t even provide their own support people with any tools whatsoever to determine why mail goes to junk. Trust me, I’ve dealt with them and I know how useless they are in this regards. So, it’s hard to say. Post the headers or there is no way to help. Do not obscure the domain names or IP addresses.

Comment: Add the address to your address book.  Mail is sometimes routed to spam simply because the sender is not in your address book.

Comment: Is your spf valid? Check https://dmarcian.com/spf-survey/. Same with DKIM. Also, implement DMARC set to reporting. You can use a free service like dmarcian.com for the reporting. I'm not sure if it's causation or just correlation but a client's deliverability improved dramatically when I helped them fix email authentication, including dmarc.

Comment: I'd say post what you have in terms of DNS entries (using example.com to maintain privacy).

Comment: Though I just noticed this was posted back in March so maybe the issue's been resolved by now?

Comment: As far as spam filters are concerned, trying to send from a new domain or IP is like trying to get a mortgage with no credit score. It's assumed spam until proven otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you register a brand new domain and set up hosting for it, check if your new IP address is blacklisted. It could well be that, since old IP addresses are 'recycled', you have obtained an IP address that was formerly owned by a spammer.

The way to go then, is either destroy your setup with the stained IP address and start over with a fresh one, or (I wouldn't recommend this if it's possible to go with the first option), apply a request for whitelisting the IP address at the various blacklisting organisations.

To have a look what Outlook thinks of your IP address, you can submit your IP here: [Outlook.com](https://sendersupport.olc.protection.outlook.com/snds/)

Comment: I checked the ip and it is a good ip. The most reasonable reason I could figure out is that they treat any new domain(maybe only for rare tld such as .xyz?) as spam by default.

Comment: see the edit, you may check what Outlook thinks of your IP